# Powershell: List xml content of all files in a specific folder

Tags: xml, powershell

I have started with the following code

```
$alarmPath = "$rootPath\Alarmgroups" 
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $alarmPath -Recurse -Include *.algrp
```

Now I have a list of all xml files in $fileNames.

Now I try to loop through each file and load the content in a way to work with the single nodes.
I currently do not know how I can implement this. Does anyone have any advice for me ?

THX

Comment: Following might get you started: `$filenames | % {[xml]$content = Get-Content $_.FullName; "dosomething with content"}`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into the `foreach` statement and into the typeaccelerator `[xml]`. Its short for `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and accepts valid xml:

```bsh
foreach ($file in $fileNames) {
    $Content = [xml](Get-Content -Path $file.FullName)

    # Your code here
}
```

This should get your started.